# Как распаковать файл из zip который находится в папке

Tags: c#

Если скачать zip-ку, то в ней окажется папка в которой имеется нужный мне файл.
Вот код для распаковки файла без внутренней папки:

```
string driverName = "chromedriver.exe";

using (var zipFileStream = await driverZipResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
using (var chromeDriverWriter = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create)) {
    var entry = zipArchive.GetEntry(driverName);
    using Stream chromeDriverStream = entry.Open();
    await chromeDriverStream.CopyToAsync(chromeDriverWriter);
}
```

Comment: Так, и в чем проблема пройтись по всем файлам и найти именно тот, который вам нужен? Все файлы находятся, на сколько я помню, в `zipArchive.Entries`, ну а дальше, например `if (entry.FullName.EndWith(driverName)) { распаковываем }`. Кстати, об этом всем сказано [в документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries).